# Define a macro that takes a structure instance and calls 'free' for each 'void*' member

Tags: c, macros

I have several similar structure types.

Each type holds several members of various types.

For example:

```
struct A
{
    char  a1;
    short a2;
    void* a3;
    int   a4;
    void* a5;
};

struct B
{
    void* b1;
    long  b2;
    void* b3;
    void* b4;
};
```

I want to define a macro that takes a structure instance and calls `free` for each `void*` member.

I assume that `__VA_ARGS__` might be useful here, but I'm not quite sure how.

Any alternative ideas (including runtime solutions) will also be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use C11 or limit yourself to GCC and Clang?

Comment: CPP macros cannot do "pack expansion" or any kind of structural rearrangement of the variadic pack arguments. All you can do is emit them in a sequence.

Comment: @Mabus: To be honest, I am using C++, but I am **not allowed** to have an additional V-Table pointer in each structure, because these structures are marshaled and passed between managed code (C#) and native code. So you may assume C++ compiler at hand. Thanks.

Comment: @KerrekSB: C macros are what I'm looking for.

Comment: What most people does in such a case is to just implement a function, `void free_A(struct A *a) {free(a->b1); free(a->b3); free(a->b4);}` and similarly a free_B() function.

Comment: @barakmanos: That is what I was talking about.

Comment: @nos: I have more than two structure types (the above was just an example)!!!

Comment: I think that if you are using C++ maybe it can be done with templates, but I'm a C guy, so I don't know how :-).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe with X Macros?

```
#define structAFields \
    X(char, a1, ) \
    X(short, a2, ) \
    X(void*, a3, ) \
    X(int, a4, ) \
    X(void*, a5, ) \

#define X(A, B, C) A B C;
struct A
{
    structAFields
};
#undef X

#define X(A, B, C) if(strcmp(#A, "void*") == 0) *((void **)((void *)(&a->B))) = malloc(2);
void mallocA(struct A * a)
{
    structAFields
}
#undef X

#define X(A, B, C) if(strcmp(#A, "void*") == 0) free(*((void **)((void *)(&a->B))));
void freeA(struct A * a)
{
    structAFields
}
#undef X

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct A a;

    mallocA(&a);
    freeA(&a);
}
```

Comment: I had also thought about X macros, but Mabus beat me to implementing them. (And yes, they're horrible. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible, C does not have any introspection at that level built in.

The classic approach is to add runtime type information to the structures, e.g. have

```
typedef enum {
  StructType_A,
  StructType_B
} StructType;
```

then add one of those to very beginning of each structure:

```
struct A {
  StructType type;
  ...
};
```

Now you can write a function that checks which type of structure it got a pointer to, and does the proper de-allocation:

```
void free_struct(void *s)
{
  const StructType type = *(StructType *) s;

  switch(type)
  {
  case StructType_A:
    {
      struct A *ap = s;
      free(ap->a3);
      free(ap->a5);
    }
    break;
  case StructType_B:
    {
      ...
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

You could of course do the actual `free()` calls differently, for instance by having a list of field offsets for each of the supported types, rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I believe that this is essentially the same implementing a different function for each structure type, which is what I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

X macros can implement the single definition, various behaviour mechanism, and Mabus has shown an example. I'd like to expand on the idea by using two X macros (or a single XY macro, rather), one for unmanaged scalar entries and one for pointers.

The structure definitions would look like this:

```
#define STRUCT_A(SCAL, PTR) \
    SCAL(int i)             \
    SCAL(double x)          \
    PTR(p1)                 \
    PTR(p2)

#define STRUCT_B(SCAL, PTR) \
    PTR(p)                  \
    PTR(q)                  \
    PTR(r)

#define STRUCT_C(SCAL, PTR) \
    SCAL(int x)             \
    SCAL(int y)             \
    PTR(r)
```

That's arguably ugly, but I don't really see any other way. There are two inner macros `SCAL` and `PTR`, and they are passed as arguments instead of being `#defined` and `#undef`ined before and after invoking the main macro.

Now we need macros that implement definition and clean-up for the structs:

```
#define SCAL_DEF(X) X;
#define PTR_DEF(X) void *X;

#define SCAL_FREE(X) 
#define PTR_FREE(X) free(TMP__STRUCT->X);

#define STRUCT_DEF(A) struct A { STRUCT_##A(SCAL_DEF, PTR_DEF) }

#define STRUCT_FREE(A, a) do {          \
    struct A *TMP__STRUCT = a;          \
    STRUCT_##A(SCAL_FREE, PTR_FREE)     \
} while (0)
```

Only the last two, `STRUCT_DEF` and `STRUCT_FREE` are used in client code, and they're used like this:

```
STRUCT_DEF(A);

void a_init(struct A *a)
{
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(*a));
    // initialise a
}

void a_do_stuff(struct A *a)
{
    // do stuff with a
}

void a_free(struct A *a)
{
    // clean-up a other than freeing void *
    STRUCT_FREE(A, a);
}
```

These macros use token-pasting and rely on `struct Thingy` being defined by the X macro `STRUCT_Thingy`.

I think that's not too bad if you place the X macro just before the `STRUCT_DEF`, but:

- The unmanaged and managed types are distinguished by two different macros, which means that the user has to make the distinction when writing the macro, so it's not "automatic".
- The user has to provide the name of the macros as arguments in the main X macro, which might be a source of error.
- The clean-up macro relies on a temporary variable with an unlikely name, which is not very clean coding.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use an array of `void *`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define free_voids(obj) free_voids(obj, sizeof(obj) / sizeof(obj[0]))

struct A
{
    char    a1;
    short   a2;
    #define a3 voids[0]
    int     a4;
    #define a5 voids[1]
    void      *voids[2];
};

struct B
{
    #define b1 voids[0]
    long    b2;
    #define b3 voids[1]
    #define b4 voids[2]
    void      *voids[3];
};

void (free_voids)(void **obj, size_t elems)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < elems; i++) {
        free(obj[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct A *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    struct B *b = malloc(sizeof *b);

    a->a1 = 1;
    a->a2 = 1;
    a->a3 = malloc(1);
    a->a4 = 1;
    a->a5 = malloc(1);
    free_voids(a->voids);
    free(a);

    b->b1 = malloc(1);
    b->b2 = 1;
    b->b3 = malloc(1);
    b->b4 = malloc(1);
    free_voids(b->voids);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when two struct fields have the same name, or when a struct field is named like other struct/function/variable?

Comment: @Mabus, yes, that‘s a problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach: Define a *managed* area in a structure that contains all void pointers that you want to handle automatically:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;

    MANAGED(p, q, r);
};
```

This structure has two integers and three managed void pointers `p`, `q` and `r` and behaves like:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;

    void *p;
    void *q;
    void *r;
};
```

There can only be one managed area of void pointers in each struct. When cleaning up, just invoke:

```
void a_free(struct A *a)
{
    FREE_MANAGED(a);   // free(a->p); free(a->q); free(a->r);
}
```

This minimal interface can be implemented with these macros:

```
typedef void *managed_t;

#define MANAGED(...)                            \
    managed_t managed_begin_;                   \
    managed_t __VA_ARGS__;                      \
    managed_t managed_end_

#define FREE_MANAGED(S) do {                    \
        managed_t *p_ = &(S)->managed_begin_;   \
        managed_t *end_ = &(S)->managed_end_;   \
        while (++p_ < end_) free(*p_);          \
    } while (0)
```

The need for the special type `managed_t` arises, because it allows to expand the macro to a one-line definition of many pointers of one type vie the `__VA_ARGS__` argument taken as whole. Pointers can't be declared by this method, because it would yield something like ´void *a, b, c`, ofg which only the first is a pointer. Typedefs in C are aliases to types, so no harm is done and`managed_t`is equivalent to`void *` and effectively hidden from the user.

The macro's ease of use comes at the cost of two additional sentinel entries, which are also `managed_t` types. (This might be wasteful, but simplifies implementation. I can imagine that a managed approach is only useful for structs with many entries, though, such that two additional pointers don't weigh in too heavy.)

This solution is macro-only (aside from the `typedef`) and can be placed in a heared file.

Answer (score 1):

A similar alternative to X-macros is higher-order macros. They're slightly more complicated to get used to, but closer to normal functional programming, and tend to enable a much lighter syntax in the end result code.

Using [`M_FOR_EACH` etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203454/1366431) (linked to limit clutter in this answer), you can define macros that iterate over a lightweight list of members to produce a struct definition and any kind of handling function:

```
#define DECLARE(N) DECLARE_(N, M_ID STRUCT_##N)   // not CONC
#define DECLARE_(N, ...) \
    struct N { M_FOR_EACH(SEMIC, __VA_ARGS__) }; \
    void M_CONC(free_, N) (struct N * s) { M_FOR_EACH(FREE_FIELD, __VA_ARGS__) }

#define SEMIC(D) D;
#define FREE_FIELD(F) M_CONC(FREEVOIDP_, M_NARGS(M_CONC(TRYFREE_, F)))(M_CONC(DOFREE_, F))
#define TRYFREE_voidp %,%
#define DOFREE_voidp
#define FREEVOIDP_1(F)
#define FREEVOIDP_2(F) free(s->F);

typedef void * voidp;


#define STRUCT_A (char  a1, \
                  short a2, \
                  voidp a3, \
                  int   a4, \
                  voidp a5)
DECLARE(A)

#define STRUCT_B (voidp b1, \
                  long  b2, \
                  voidp b3, \
                  voidp b4)
DECLARE(B)
```

Define your struct as a simple list of members (this is much easier on the eye than X-macros in user code), with any that you want to be picked up by the free operation declared as type `voidp`. (It won't work with plain `void*`, but I feel like the typedef provides a little more documentation of the fact that something special happens to these fields, so it's acceptable.) The name of the define must begin with `STRUCT_`; this makes it possible for the declaring macro to separate the name from the body later.

The first loop just inserts semicolons so that the list can be pasted inside a struct declaration.

The second loop is able to identify `voidp` members (by prepending `TRYFREE_` to the type and seeing which ones expand to multi-token sequences) and only emits a free function for those. This is where the typedef becomes necessary: it isn't possible to separate the `*` from the member name using the preprocessor. (The alternative is to comma-separate the types from the member names in the original definition, which is hard to read.)