# trouble with specialising template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I often use the following construction for converting run-time (dynamic) arguments into compile-time (static) arguments

```
namespace Foo {
  enum struct option { A,B,C,D,E,F };

  template<template<option> class Func, typename... Args>
  auto Switch(option opt, Args&&...args)
  -> decltype(Func<option::A>::act(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  {
    switch(opt) {
    case option::A : return Func<option::A>::act(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    case option::B : return Func<option::B>::act(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // etc.
  }
}
```

For example

```
template<Foo::option>
void compile_time(std::string const&);         // given

namespace {
  template<Foo::option Opt>
  struct Helper {
    static void act(std::string const&str) { compile_time<Opt>(str); }
  };
}

void run_time_arg(Foo::option opt, std::string const&str)
{
  Switch<CompileTimeArg>(opt,str);
}
```

So far so good. But now I have another `template` argument and want also `blah()` to have that same `template` argument. That is, conceptually I want to

```
template<int, Foo::option>
void compile_time(std::string const&);         // given

namespace {
  template<int Bar, Foo::option Opt>
  struct Helper {
    static void act(std::string const&str) { compile_time<Bar,Opt>(str); }
  };
}

template<int Bar>
void blah(Foo::option opt, std::string const&str)
{
  template<Foo::option Opt> using BarHelper = Helper<Bar,Opt>;
  Switch<BarHelper>(opt, str);
}
```

but, of course, that is not allowed (a `template` within block scope in function `blah()`). **So what is the correct solution?**

Note that I can put everything within an auxiliary class template

```
namespace {
  template<int Bar>
  struct Auxiliary
  {
    template<Foo::option Opt> using BarHelper = Helper<Bar,Opt>;
    static void blah(Foo::option opt, std::string const&str)
    { Switch<BarHelper>(opt, str); }
  };
}

template<int Bar>
void blah(Foo::option opt, std::string const&str)
{ Auxiliary<Bar>::blah(opt, str); }
```

But that's clumsy and unsatisfying. **Is there an alternative or better solution?**
I tried this:

```
template<typename X, typename Y, X x, template<X,Y> class C>
struct specialise {
  template<Y y> using special = C<x,y>;
};

template<int Bar>
void blah(Foo::option opt, std::string const&str)
{
  using Aux = specialise<int, Foo::option, Bar, Helper>
  Switch<Aux::special>(opt, str); }
}
```

but gcc (5.1.0) complains that `S::special` is parsed as a non-type while instantiation yields a type ... which is wrong (I think): instantiation yields a *template* (anyway inserting `typename` as suggested doesn't help). **So what's wrong and/or how to do this correct/better?**

Comment: Are you aware you are using `specialize` and `specialise`? It looks confusing to me.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek fixed that.

Comment: Just by curiousity I wonder if this one is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202250/c-template-instantiation-avoiding-long-switches ?

Comment: @user2672165 in some sense yes, but not directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword to add is not `typename` as it is not a type, but `template`.

So, the call should be

```
template<int Bar>
void blah(Foo::option opt, std::string const& str)
{
    using Aux = specialise<int, Foo::option, Bar, Helper>
    Switch<Aux::template special>(foo, ptr, str);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6132c1a3ace2e30d)

Comment: correct. I had figured this out by myself mean while ... and thx for the edits -- you obviously tried this out! I've only ever seen this usage of the `template` key word when followed by `<>`, e.g. `ptr->template func<0>()`.