# c++ protobuf oneof deserializing generically

Tags: c++, generics, reflection, protocol-buffers

I am wondering if there is a generic way to deserialize a message that has a `oneof` sub-message. The `oneof` message will contain many other messages. Right now, I can get it working using a `switch` statement on the `case` number and call the appropriate getter. But, if there is a generic way so that in the future I don't have to keep adding new cases.

I would like to eliminate the cases and have something generic where I could get the message type i.e. `Exit` and call the correct getter. Is there a way to do it with reflection? I looked for examples online but couldn't find much.

**proto file:**

```proto
message AllClientMessages {
    oneof client_message {
        util.client.command Exit exit = 1
        util.client.command SendNew sendnew = 2
        util.client.command CancelAll cancelAll = 3
        // ... (more than 60 messages)
    }
}
```

**Code** (`buf` contains the serialized message):

```cpp
const std::unique_ptr<google::protobuf::Message> ProtoBuilder::deserialize(char* buf)
{
    AllClientMessages clientMsg;
    clientMsg.ParseFromString(buf);

    switch(clientMsg.client_message_case())
    {
    case AllClientMessages::kExitFieldNumber: //generate enums
        return make_unique<Exit>(clientMsg.exit());

    case AllClientMessages::kSendNewFieldNumber:
        return make_unique<SendNew>(clientMsg.sendnew());

    // I access the getter and return unique_ptr to base protobuf Message.
    // ... I do this for each case.
    }
}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202250/c-template-instantiation-avoiding-long-switches

Comment: BTW, you should test the return value (Boolean) of `ParseFromString()` before you proceed to use the parsed message i.e. `if ( !clientMsg.ParseFromString(buf) ) { /* handle_error_here */ }`.

Comment: another question about ParseFromString(buf). : will it also populate the oneof message. or do i need to call ParseFromString on the oneof object as well. I am getting the default values.

Comment: The binary message would be deserialized and the result would be the populated message object. If it's part of the message, it should automatically be deserialized. **Question**: Why are you using a [oneof](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof)? It seems like it should have been an [enum](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#enum) instead. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/rnnx8x.

Comment: Got it. I see that `oneof` provides you kind-of automated enum and object handling facilities together. Suggestion: You should have a default value (index ZERO) as described in the [Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#oneof) article to make error-handling more robust in case the message is not properly set.

Comment: Yes I got it to work. The oneof message is getting de-serialzied. Yes it like a huge variant where I can put any of my messages in and I don't need to provide a header file with the msg_type. What sucks is protobuf doesn't know when a message ends so i have to put the size before each proto message and parse and split the buffer myself. it would be nice if each time you call ParseFromString it would just parse the first message in the buffer. When i give it a buffer with many messages it seems to be giving me the last message.

Comment: As for the generic part there are a few issues. Once I parse the oneof message I need to know which message is set. I then need to get the underlying type and know the method to get the object from the oneof message. Here is an example of the switch

Comment: switch(clientMsg.client_message_case())
    {
        case AllClientMessages::kExitFieldNumber:
            return make_pair(make_unique<ExitSpec>(clientMsg.exit()), Exit);

        case AllClientMessages::kWaitFieldNumber:
            return make_pair(make_unique<WaitSpec>(clientMsg.wait()), Wait);

Comment: sorry about the formatting. so for instance if the first message is set this case wil be set kExitFieldNumber . from that I need to get the message type  ExitSpec as well as call the proper method clientMsg.exit() - each message has a different method. Can this be done with protobuf reflection ?

Comment: Right. IMO, it seems like an overkill to manage all those commands in the ProtoBuf schema. A type and command would be enough. As for the multiple messages, you can use a repeated type (array) for the bulk message. Maybe, there's more to this whole design. You're the better judge of it.

Comment: Depending on your whole scenario, you might want to look at [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/).

Comment: So if i don't use the oneof message i will then have to add the msg_type to the header. but i still have the same issue that for each message i need to call the ParseFromString on that message, so i still have to have code for each message. I think this could be done with protobuf reflection but there is a lack of tutorials and there no documentation by google on reflection. The documentation is very basic.

Comment: For the 2nd issue an (array won't work). When you read from the socket you can get 65k bytes. you have to manage it yourself. read the header get the message size then give ParseFromString a buffer of the right size. you have to manage splitting the buffer for each object.

Comment: The buffer can be 1 or more messages . Not necessarily the same message. it can be many different ones. What I was saying it would be nice if i pass the 65k buffer to ParseFromString it would just parse the first message. Then you could call ByteSIze() on the message to get the size of the message and then move the buffer pointer. Also it would be nice if they accepted a string_view instead of string. i have to make extra copies

Comment: Is this the complete type of one message `util.client.command Exit`, right?

Comment: For reflection to work, I believe that you have to know the correct `MessageDescriptor`. You might find a similar question doing something like this not so long ago. Check the [`protocol-buffers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers) tag.

Comment: As for the message buffer, you can write a wrapper that does exactly what you described earlier. ProroBuf is a data exchange format and it doesn't deal with the communication layer. So, to receive the message into exact parsable chunks would be the responsibility of the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that should work for this.

Some time at initialization you can construct a map between one-of field number and index.

```
auto descriptor = clientMsg.GetDescriptor();
auto oneofDescriptor = descriptor->FindOneofByName("client_message");

// Map from oneof field number to field index
std::unordered_map<int, int> numberToIndexMap;

for (int idx = 0; idx < oneofDescriptor->field_count(); idx++)
{
    auto fieldDescriptor = oneofDescriptor->field(idx);
    numberToIndexMap[fieldDescriptor->number()] = idx;
}
```

Then later on you can use that map to access the correct field indicated by the *type_case*.

```
auto reflection = clientMsg.GetReflection();
auto descriptor = clientMsg.GetDescriptor();
auto oneofDescriptor = descriptor->FindOneofByName("client_message");
const auto & message = reflection->GetMessage(clientMsg, oneofDescriptor->field(numberToIndexMap.at(int(event.type_case()))));

// If we want a new copy to return as unique ptr
auto copy = std::make_unique<google::protobuf::Message>(message.New());
copy->CopyFrom(message);

return copy;
```

I haven't been able to find a way to get the one-of descriptor without hardcoding the name of the one-of, which feels kind of lame. It would be nice to be about to get it directly from AllClientMessages.client_message().